# Use connect, signals and slots by iterator

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, iterator, signals-slots

I'm trying to build a GUI with a lot of buttons to be connected to one slot. I therefore would like to add them into a vector and then connect all of these by an iterator.

Example:

```
std::vector<QRadioButton*> buttonVec;
buttonVec.push_back(ui->radioA);
buttonVec.push_back(ui->radioB);
buttonVec.push_back(ui->radioC);
//...
for(std::vector<QRadioButton*>::iterator it = buttonVec.begin(); it != buttonVec.end(), it++)
    connect(*it, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(handleRadioVec()));
//...
```

Unfortunately, this leads to an error during runtime (not building), where the same connect-code line but with the direct objects runs without any problems:

> QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::released() to
>   MainWindow::handleRadioVec()

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Judging from your use of `ui`, you're using UIC. Are you calling `setupUi` before you fill `buttonVec`?

Comment: @Angew that's it, if you'd make this as an answer I'll close this question

Comment: Use `clicked` signal, instead of `released`

Comment: @SaZ are you indicating a QT-bug, or why should I change?

Comment: `released` - is mouse-only event. `clicked` - will handle both, keyboard / mouse / touch devices.

Comment: @SaZ ah thanks for the hint. I thought this was only to make clear when the signal (at beginning or end of the interaction) is emitted

Comment: This question lacks the necessary detail: it is not obvious at all what's missing from the constructor since you didn't bother providing a complete constructor definition that reproduces the problem. Please amend your question to match the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `ui`, which I assume means your widgets are set up using the UIC compiler. Bear in mind that you have to actually create the widgets (by calling `setupUi`) before you can use them. Until then, `ui->anything` will be null pointers.

So call `setupUi(this)` before you fill `buttonVec`.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a hint. If you are using C++11, you may write more clear (and more fast) code:

```
const auto buttons =
  {
    ui->radioA,
    ui->radioB,
    // ...
  };
for ( auto btn : buttons )
  connect( btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::handleRadioVec );
```

Comment: yes but I guess this indicates that all buttons on the whole GUI are part of one group - e.g. group all tires of a car, but what if I want to seperate the tires for each car from each other ?

Comment: It depends on your logic. I just proposed to use initialization list, auto types, range-based for loop and Qt5 connection syntax. Code readability grows up ;)